# login to the SharePoint 2013 using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, sharepoint-2013

Is their any way to login to the **SharePoint 2013** using c# code and get the token of sharepoint 2013, if yes then how can i do?
means user will put username and password from the client side and auth is window auth configured on sharepoint 2013 in my case
also please specify the **SharePoint 2013 config** also

Now created a api in mvc and it's working with netwrokcredential class which is available in c# but i am not getting the token for the sharepoint

Answer (score 0):

You can use client side object model to create context with your credentials.

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://site_url/"))
{
    context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user_login", "user_password", "DOMAIN");
    List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("My list");
    context.Load(list);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    Console.WriteLine(list.Id);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answ, but how can i get the token from sharepoint 2013 using above code?

Comment: Sorry, maybe i don't understand it right. Do you try to develop win form/console app or sharepoint app?